# Playwright automation cant bypass location popup

Tags: node.js, typescript, browser-automation, webautomation, playwright

I'm attempting to use Playwright (https://github.com/microsoft/playwright) and I'm met by the location popup when I try to test the library. Is there a way to bypass this popup or at least click either "Block" or "Allow"? I've tried using the `Page.on("popup")` event but it isn't quite working the way I was expecting it to.

[image: popup]

Comment: How about `page.on('dialog', ...)`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `grantPermissions` function to grant geolocation for the site.

```js
await context.grantPermissions(['geolocation'], { origin: 'https://www.bestbuy.com' });
```

Comment: not working for me on Chromium

Answer (score 1):

This is how I grant geo localization on my script

```js
const { chromium } = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  // const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false});
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  await context.grantPermissions(['geolocation'], { origin: 'yourPage.com' });
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto('yourPage.com');
  browser.close();
})();
```

here is the documentation [playwright.dev](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-grant-permissions)

Comment: where to write this code?

Comment: This code should be written in a JavaScript file. You can create a new file and name it `script.js`, and then copy and paste the code into this file. After that, you have to execute it, navigate to the directory where your `script.js` file is located using your terminal. Then, run the following command: `node script.js`.